# why my jquery code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
        var i=0;
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#tolevel_" + (i+1) ).click(function(){
              $("#level_" + i).hide(500,'swing', function(){
                  $("#level_" +(i+1)).show(500, 'swing', function(){
                      i=i+1;
                  });

              });
           });
            $("#backtolevel_" + (i-1) ).click(function(){
                $("#level_" + i).hide(500,'swing', function(){
                    $("#level_" +(i-1)).show(500, 'swing', function(){
                        i=i-1;
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ok here is my jquery. The level ids are divs and tolevel and backtolevel are two buttons in each. for example if the div id is "level_1" the ids of the buttons in that div are "backtolevel_0" and "tolevel_2".
Ok it only works the first time. it doesn't matter on what level I am. I have tested it on different levels but it only works once. don't know why! can you guys help me? I think somewhat the incrementing or decrementing are not working.

Comment: You are only attaching the event handlers one time. At level 0.

Comment: And how do you expect it to bind to the next level when you do not change `i`? There is no reason to be using `i`. Use parent and child selectors.

Comment: What's wrong with using a class?

Comment: how do you mean?! the i is global and it is incrementing in the function.

Comment: @ArmanMomeni That's not how it works

Comment: so how should I do that? i++?

Comment: @epascarello OP is using `i=i+1;` BUT inside event handler called after binding event.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle for these kinds of questions?

Comment: I even put an alert to show me the value of i. and it is showing 1. but I guess it will change back to 0.

Comment: Ok now I got it. it's not a realtime thing. I have to write the code for every single button of mine. so I guess a loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("[id^=tolevel_]").click(function(){
                var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
                var number = currentID.replace("tolevel_","");//get the number in string format
                number = parseInt(number);
                var i = number -1;
                $("#level_" + i).hide(500,'swing', function(){
                  $("#level_" +(i+1)).show(500, 'swing', function(){

                  });
                });
           });

            $("[id^=backtolevel_]").click(function(){
                var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
                var number = currentID.replace("backtolevel_","");//get the number in string format
                number = parseInt(number);
                var i = number + 1;
                $("#level_" + i).hide(500,'swing', function(){
                    $("#level_" +(i-1)).show(500, 'swing', function(){

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It user `jquery's Attribute Starts With Selector. See more about it at https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. Really no need to write code for each and every element. This should work.

Comment: Wow Thank you for helping me instead of downvoting my question I replaced and it is working like a charm, but I have to study it as how it is working. have no idea, I learned jquery from w3schools. Thank you very much.